# How to use different price.phtml file for different views?

Tags: magento

I want to use custom new_price.phtml file for New Products block and price.phtml for all product view.I ahve seen some examples but as i am very new so i don't know how to implement thrm.

Can anyone tell me the proper steps for this.

Below is the Code for new.phtml.

```
      <?php
                // some helpers
                $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
                $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
                $catalog = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setStoreId($storeId);
                $productCount = $this->getData('num_products');
            ?>
<?php 
$visibility = array(
                      Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                      Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
                  );
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')    
                        ->setStoreId($storeId)
                        ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
                        ->distinct(true) 
                       //->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility)
                       //  ->addFieldToFilter('qty', array('gteq' => 1))
                      // ->addAttributeToFilter('is_in_stock',0)              
                        //->addOrderedQty()
                          ->setOrder('entity_id', 'desc')
                        ->setPageSize($productCount);
                        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
                        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);
                        Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
/* To display product by category id */
  if($categoryId=$this->getData('category_id')){
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
        $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
      }
                ?>
          <?php      // if no products are currently sell, display some text
                 if (!$collection->count()) :
        ?>
        <p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products sell at the moment.') ?></p>
        <?php else : ?>

<div class="products_slider">
<div class="product-title pro-name">
  <span class=""><?php echo $this->__('New Products') ?></span>
</div> <!--product-title-->
<a id="products_slider_prev1" class="jcarousel-prev-horizontal" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
<a id="products_slider_next1" class="jcarousel-next-horizontal" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
<!-- BEGIN SLIDER CONTAINER -->
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class=" jcarousel-skin-tango">
    <div class="jcarousel-container jcarousel-container-horizontal" style="position: relative; display: block;">
      <div class="jcarousel-clip jcarousel-clip-horizontal" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
        <ul class="products-grid-home jcarousel-list jcarousel-list-horizontal" id="products_slider1" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; top: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; left: 0px; width: 2970px;">
        <?php
                $_collectionSize = $collection->count();
                $_columnCount = 4;
                $i = 0;
                $v8=1;
                foreach ($collection as $_product) :
                        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($_product->getId());
        ?>
            <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>

            <?php endif ?>

                <li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-1 jcarousel-item-1-horizontal<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>" style="float: left; list-style: none outside none;"> 
                  <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                     <?php  //echo $this->helper('vistasettings')->getLabel($_product);  ?>
                     <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(228,319); ?>" class="small-image" width="228"  alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                   <?php /*?> <?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
                    foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
                    ?>
                     <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $image->getFile())->resize(228, 319); ?>" class="thumbnail" width="228"  alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>"/>
                    <?php }  ?><?php */?>
                  </a>
            <script type="text/javascript">
             /*   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery("#various8<?php echo $v8; ?>").fancybox({
                'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
                'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
                'onClosed'      :  function() { }
                });
                });*/
            </script>
                <!--  <a href="#inline8<?php echo $v8; ?>" id="various8<?php echo $v8; ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Quick View') ?>" class="product-detail-bnt">&nbsp;</a>-->

<!-- POP UP --><div style="display: none;"><div id="inline8<?php echo $v8; ?>" class="info-box">
<div class="product-view">
  <div class="product-essential">
    <div class="product-img-box">
       <div class="product-image">
          <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class ="cloud-zoom" id="zoom1" rel="adjustX:10, adjustY:-2, zoomWidth:400, zoomHeight:400">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(260,260); ?>" width="260" height="260" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />                 
          </a>
       </div> <!--product-image-->
       <div class="more-images">
        <div class="more-views">
        <div class="more-views thumbnailscroller carousel">
        <div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;" class="thumbnail-viewport">
 <ul style="width: 1200%; transition-duration: 0s; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);" id="thumbscroller<?php echo $v8; ?>" class="thumbscroller slides">

     <?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
          foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) : ?>
        <li   style="width: 100px; float: left; display: block;">
          <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $image->getFile()); ?>" class="cloud-zoom-gallery" rel="useZoom: 'zoom1', smallImage: '<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $image->getFile())->resize(260,260); ?>' ">
            <img class="zoom-tiny-image" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $image->getFile())->resize(80, 80); ?>" width="80" height="80" alt=""/>
          </a>
        </li>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    </div>

 <ul class="thumbnail-direction-nav"><li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="thumbnail-prev"><?php echo $this->__('Previous');?></a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="thumbnail-next"><?php echo $this->__('Next');?></a></li></ul>
  </div><!--thumbnailscroller carousel-->
   </div><!--more-views-->

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $mtkb(window).load(function(){
        $mtkb('.thumbnailscroller').flexslider({
            namespace: "thumbnail-",
            animation: "slide",
            animationLoop: true,
            itemWidth: 250,
            itemMargin: 0,
            slideshow: true,
            minItems: 1,
            maxItems: 1,
            directionNav: true,
            controlNav: false,
            move: 1,
            touch: true,
        });
    });
</script>



 </div><!--more-images-->

    </div> <!--product-img-box-->
    <div class="product-shop">
      <div class="product-name">
        <h1><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>">
                    <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()); ?> 
            </a>
        </h1>
      </div> <!--product-name-->
      <div class="short-description"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?></div>
      <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
      <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
     <div class="add-to-box">
<form action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_<?php echo $_product->getId()?>"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
 <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
       <div class="add-to-cart">
          <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>        
              <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty"  maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
             <button class="button-arrow button-up" type="button"><?php echo $this->__('Increase');?></button>
             <button class="button-arrow button-down" type="button"><?php echo $this->__('Decrease');?></button>   
       </div> <!--add-to-cart-->
 <?php endif; ?>
         <div class="add-to-cart">
         <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
               <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="this.form.submit()"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></button>
         <?php else: ?>
               <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
         <?php endif; ?>
         </div><!-- add-to-cart-->
         <ul class="add-to-links">
            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                  <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="button link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to wishlist');?></a></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
           <?php /*?> <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                  <li><span class="separator">|</span><a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="button link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to compare');?></a></li>
            <?php endif; ?><?php */?>
         </ul>
         <span class="email-friend"><a class="button link-friend" href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?></a></span>

 </form>
     </div> <!--add-to-box-->

    </div> <!--product-shop-->
  </div> <!--product-essential-->
</div> <!--product-view-->
</div></div> <!-- End POP UP-->

<!-- BEGIN PROD IMAGE DETAIL -->
                  <div class="prod_image_detail">
                  <div class="inner">
                     <a class="product-name" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php //echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>
                        <?php $prod_name = $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ; 
                        /*if(strlen($prod_name) > 20) {echo substr($prod_name,0,20)."...";}else {echo $prod_name;}*/echo $prod_name;?></a>
                          <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                     <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                     </div>
                     <div class="actions">
                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                           <button type="button"  title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></button>
                        <?php else: ?>
                           <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <span class="add-to-links"> <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                  <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="button link-wishlist" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to wishlist');?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to wishlist');?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
           <?php /*?> <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                  <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="button link-compare" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to compare');?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to compare');?></a>
            <?php endif; ?><?php */?> </span><!--add-to-links-->

                     </div> <!--actions-->

                  </div> <!--prod_image_detail-->
                </li>

            <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>

            <?php endif ?>
             <?php $v8++; ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
          </ul>
       </div> <!--jcarousel-clip jcarousel-clip-horizontal-->
     </div> <!--jcarousel-container jcarousel-container-horizontal-->
  </div> <!-- jcarousel-skin-tango-->
</div> <!--slider-container-->
</div> <!--products_slider-->
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script> 



<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var jwidth=$('.products-grid-home').width();
        function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel) {
           $('#products_slider_next1').bind('click', function(event) {
                 carousel.next();
                 if(jwidth==2800){
                    return false;
                }
            });

            $('#products_slider_prev1').bind('click', function(event) {
                carousel.prev();
                return false;
            });
        };

    /*$('#products_slider1').jcarousel({
            scroll:1,
            visible:4,
            setupCallback: scrollCheck,
            initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback,
            buttonNextHTML: null,
            itemFallbackDimension:240,
            buttonPrevHTML: null,
            animation: {
            duration: 500,
            easing:   'linear',
            complete: function() {
            }
          }

    });*/
     $('#products_slider1').jcarousel({
            scroll: 1,
        initCallback:mycarousel_initCallback,
            buttonNextHTML: null,
            buttonPrevHTML: null
    });
    function scrollCheck(carousel) {
    if (carousel.options.size <= carousel.options.visible) {
        // If there is enough room to display all available items, then disable scrolling
        carousel.stopAuto();
    }
}
});
</script>

        <?php endif ?>
```

I am very new on Magento.
Can anyone tell me the steps to go this?

Comment: put your new product collection code in here??

Comment: did you try the solution I gave ?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify it in the backend on the design tab of the product. if you want to do it programmatically, please precise your question with the way you import products...